# Question on autoregressive equation

Tags: autoregressive

I was given a reduced form VAR model, where the dependent variable is inflation, and independent variables include inflation lagged by four periods (L.Inflation) and other exogenous variables.

The lagged part is the AR component of the model. Shouldn't the AR include L1.Inflation, L2.Inflation, L3.Inflation as well? Is this still an AR equation without these three terms?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is still an auto regression, only assuming that the coefficient of the first three lags are zero.